# Random i.i.d variable series

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-limit-theorems

I want to prove that if {$X_n$}$_{n\in N}$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables, non-degenerated in 0, it means, none of them are almost sure  equal to 0, then

$P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}$ converges $) = 0$

Some advice would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Use Kolomogorov's $0-1$ law and Kolomogorov's three series theorem.

Comment: Hint: Notice that $X_n(\omega) \to 0$ when $\sum_{n} X_n(\omega)$ is a convergent series.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I thought of that but I don't know how to use the three series theorem with the non-degenerated condition given